# In Amazon Redshift, running GRANT as a superuser does not grant privileges on table to a regular user

Tags: postgresql, redshift

I'm trying to run a query in Amazon Redshift, but I keep getting the error

`permission denied for relation mytable`

As far as I understand, this is a privileges issue.

According to this question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520361/permission-denied-for-relation

Running this command as a superuser:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE mytable TO myuser;`

Should get rid of the problem, but it's not.

I'm connecting to Amazon Redshift as a superuser, issuing the command and Amazon Redshift replies back with a:

`GRANT executed successfully` message plus the running time.

However, when I try to query that table as the user I'm granting the privileges to, Amazon Redshift keeps showing the error

permission denied for relation mytable

I tried to elevate `myuser` privileges to superuser as well, but that didn't work either.

Also, the error is only shown to that particular table, I can select other tables with that user without a problem, but as soon as I try to run a `SELECT` or `EXPLAIN` on that table I get the permission error.

Any help pointing me to the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that this post has been cloned to http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/61724/7788